# How to access Common Viewer while developing eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I need to access tree structure of project/package explorer through eclipse plugin. It can be done by extending CommonNavigator class for RCP application by :

```
public  CommonViewer viewer = super.getCommonViewer();
Tree tree = viewer.getTree();
```

But I need to do it by creating a plugin and I don't know how to replicate it for plugin development.

Comment: What exactly do you need? Do you want to display projects and folder in your own view, or do you just want to access the projects in your workspace programmatically?

Comment: I need to dump tree structure of viewer in XML format. For that, I need to access the contents of the viewer from plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just fetch workspace items you are better off using `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getWorkspaceRoot().getProjects()`.

But if you want to only look at a viewer's contents, I can suggest using its content provider. Use something like:

```java
CommonViewer viewer = super.getCommonViewer();
ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider) viewer.getContentProvider();
Object rootElements[] = provider.getElements(viewer.getInput());
```